# ERC721 - Undefined amount on TransferFrom

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-721, goerli, transferfrom

I've got a standard ERC721 - OpenZeppelin wizard generated contract deployed on Goerli network.

I've minted a token and I'm trying to transfer said token to another wallet using the transferFrom and safeTransferFrom methods.

The code is pretty much standard, with only the OperatorRegistry modifier added.

```
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721Upgradeable, ERC721EnumerableUpgradeable, ERC2981)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }

    function setApprovalForAll(address operator, bool approved) public override(ERC721Upgradeable, IERC721Upgradeable) onlyAllowedOperatorApproval(operator) {
        super.setApprovalForAll(operator, approved);
    }

    function approve(address operator, uint256 tokenId) public override(ERC721Upgradeable, IERC721Upgradeable) onlyAllowedOperatorApproval(operator) {
        super.approve(operator, tokenId);
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public override(ERC721Upgradeable, IERC721Upgradeable) onlyAllowedOperator(from) {
        super.transferFrom(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public override(ERC721Upgradeable, IERC721Upgradeable) onlyAllowedOperator(from) {
        super.safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId, bytes memory data)
        public
        override(ERC721Upgradeable, IERC721Upgradeable)
        onlyAllowedOperator(from)
    {
        super.safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId, data);
    }
```

However, when I try to run the transferFrom or safeTransferFrom functions from Remix and pay with Metamask the amount appears as "undefined" added to the gas fee. Said amount should be zero.

[image: Amount_is_undefined]

No amount is being asked for on the contract or provided using the value field. The transaction works regardless of the "undefined".

I don't have a clue about why this "undefined" is appearing.
Is there any way to avoid being showed the "undefined".

Thanks,

**UPDATE:**

We've tried from a direct Metamask / web3.js integration using the following transaction parameters, same result:

```
const transactionParameters = {
 from: data.sender_address,
 to: address721,
 data: contract721.methods.transferFrom(
  data.sender_address,
  data.receptor_address,
  data.token_id
 ).encodeABI()
};

web3.eth.sendTransaction(transactionParameters)
                .on('transactionHash', function(hash) {...
```

Comment: have you tried to do that using etherscan?

Comment: Nope because I haven't had the contract certified yet.

Comment: check it there, maybe remix has a bug :/